# undefined method `to_key' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation []> Did you mean? to_set to_ary

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This is my form

```
      <%= form_for @customer do |f| %>
      <ul>
        <li><%= f.text_field  :NameAndFamilyName,class:'1', placeholder:'نام و نام خانوادگی' %></li>
        <li><input class="1" placeholder="نام و نام خانوادگی"></li>
        <li><input class="1" placeholder="تلفن همراه"></li>
        <li><input class="1" placeholder="آدرس ایمیل"></li>
        <li><input placeholder="موضوع پیام"></li>
        <li><textarea placeholder="متن پیام"></textarea></li>
        <li>
          <button>ارسال پیام</button>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <% end %>
```

This is my controller

```
    class CustomerController < ApplicationController
  def index
        @customer = Customer.all

    end

    def new
        @customer = Customer.new
    end

    def create
        @customer = Customer.new(customer_params)

        if @customer.save
            redirect_to @customer
        else
            render 'customer/index'

        end

    end
end
```

This is my migration:

```
     class CreateCustomers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
       def change
        create_table :customers do |t|
          t.string  :NameAndFamilyName
          t.integer :Phone
          t.string  :Email
          t.string  :MessageSubject
          t.text    :Message

          t.timestamps
        end
      end
    end
```

What should I do this code its not running?

I want create form but this error apears   every things is normal for me but its not running. I'm having this error:

```
undefined method `to_key' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation []>
  Did you mean? to_set to_ary
```

Comment: There's no controller, migration is twice.

Comment: You might check out the [ruby style guide for naming](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide#naming). By convention, your variables would have names like `name_and_family_name`, not `NameAndFamilyName`.

Comment: @Sebastian Palma  i edit that

Comment: @jvillian its not working

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "it's not working". I didn't recommend anything in particular. I just noted that your variable naming is unconventional in your migration. (Also, your controller code is still missing.)

Comment: What file and line number does the error message indicate? Edit your post and put a `# comment` on that line.

Comment: @jvillian sry i add controller

Comment: You should also add to your question the full error trace from your console.

Comment: this is an error <%= form_for @customer do |f| %>

Comment: Where is `customer_params` defined?

Comment: `@customer = Customer.all` should be `@customers = Customer.all`, at least.

Comment: Add the whole backtrace of the error.

Comment: Are you trying to render the form in index view?

Comment: @Santhosh yes i want render it

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have this error on index action.

```
@customer = Customer.all
```

It returns not one customer but the list of customers. So I suggest to change it on:

```
def index
  @customers = Customer.all
  @customer = Customer.new
end
```